# Locating heading text using CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have some C# code which will verify the heading text on a web page, currently located via xpath as follows.

```
Assert.AreEqual("Permissions", driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='navigation']/li[6]/h3")).Text);
```

This, as I understand, will check the text found at the end of the XPath matches the word "Permissions".

The above currently works but I would rather use CSS locators. I hear its best not to use XPath if possible.

I'm new to website testing so am not yet familiar with all this, any help will be much appreciated.

Let me know if there is more you require than what is provided above or if you have any alternate suggestions to the method already used.

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand what you are trying to do but since this has no answer after 7 hours i though i might at least mention that if you are trying to get the innerhtml of the header you can use Agile Html http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ its very easy to use. Might not be what you are looking for though.